# select結果を共通項目ごとに列分割して、再出力させたい

Tags: mysql

□やりたいこと
下記の'name'ごとに'value'列を分割して、再表示する際のSQLクエリ文についてご教授いただけますでしょうか。。

□mysqlバージョン

```
+------------+
| version()  |
+------------+
| 5.1.73-log |
+------------+
```

□現状の出力結果

```
select from_unixtime(history.clock, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'), hosts.host, items.name, history.value from history
inner join items using( itemid )
inner join hosts using( hostid )
where hosts.host like '%hoge%' 
and items.name like '%Temp%' 
and from_unixtime(clock) between '2019-03-07 00:00' and '2020-03-08 00:00'

+------------------------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+
| from_unixtime(history.clock) | host              | name      | value    |
+------------------------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+
| 2019-12-07 00:02             | hoge1             | Temp_CPU0 | -99.0000 |
| 2019-12-07 00:07             | hoge1             | Temp_CPU0 | -98.0000 |
| 2019-12-07 00:02             | hoge1             | Temp_CPU1 | -97.0000 |
| 2019-12-07 00:07             | hoge1             | Temp_CPU1 | -96.0000 |
| 2019-12-07 00:02             | hoge2             | Temp_CPU0 | -95.0000 |
| 2019-12-07 00:07             | hoge2             | Temp_CPU0 | -94.0000 |
| 2019-12-07 00:02             | hoge2             | Temp_CPU1 | -93.0000 |
| 2019-12-07 00:07             | hoge2             | Temp_CPU1 | -92.0000 |
```

□期待する出力結果

```
+------------------------------+-------------------+----------+----------+
| from_unixtime(history.clock) | host              | Temp_CPU0| Temp_CPU1
+------------------------------+-------------------+----------+----------+
| 2019-12-07 00:02             | hoge1             | -99.0000 | -97.0000 |
| 2019-12-07 00:07             | hoge1             | -98.0000 | -96.0000 |
| 2019-12-07 00:02             | hoge2             | -95.0000 | -93.0000 |
| 2019-12-07 00:07             | hoge2             | -94.0000 | -92.0000 |
```

Answer (score 0):

【回答】
　任意の'name'ごとに'value'を列挙するSQLではありませんが、`Temp_CPU0`、`Temp_CPU1`固定の'value'を１行にまとめるSQLの記述は可能です。
　副問い合わせを使用します。

【副問い合わせを使用したSQL】

```sql
select from_unixtime(CPU0.clock, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'),CPU0.host, CPU0.value as Temp_CPU0, CPU1.value as Temp_CPU1
  from
  (
     select xx.clock, xx.host, xx.name, xx.value
     from
     (
      select history.clock, hosts.host, items.name, history.value
      from history
      inner join items using( itemid )
      inner join hosts using( hostid )
      where hosts.host like '%hoge%' 
          and items.name like '%Temp%' 
          and from_unixtime(clock) between '2019-03-07 00:00' and '2020-03-08 00:00'
     ) xx
     where name like '%Temp_CPU0%'
  ) CPU0
  ,
  (
     select xx.clock, xx.host, xx.name, xx.value
     from
     (
      select history.clock, hosts.host, items.name, history.value
      from history
      inner join items using( itemid )
      inner join hosts using( hostid )
      where hosts.host like '%hoge%' 
          and items.name like '%Temp%' 
          and from_unixtime(clock) between '2019-03-07 00:00' and '2020-03-08 00:00'
     ) xx
     where name like '%Temp_CPU1%'
  ) CPU1
  where
    CPU0.host  = CPU1.host and
    CPU0.clock = CPU1.clock
;
```

【WITH句を使用したSQL】
 MySQL 8.0以降でないと使えませんが、WITH句を使用しても同じことができます。

```sql
with
  source as (
    select history.clock, hosts.host, items.name, history.value
    from history
    inner join items using( itemid )
    inner join hosts using( hostid )
    where hosts.host like '%hoge%' 
          and items.name like '%Temp%' 
          and from_unixtime(clock) between '2019-03-07 00:00' and '2020-03-08 00:00'
  ),
  cpu0 as (
    select clock, host, name, value from source where name like '%Temp_CPU0%'
  ),
  cpu1 as (
    select clock, host, name, value from source where name like '%Temp_CPU1%'
  )
select from_unixtime(cpu0.clock, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'),cpu0.host,cpu0.value as Temp_CPU0, cpu1.value as Temp_CPU1
  from 
   (select clock, host, name, value from source where name like '%Temp_CPU0%') cpu0
   ,
   (select clock, host, name, value from source where name like '%Temp_CPU1%') cpu1
  where
    cpu0.host  = cpu1.host and
    cpu0.clock = cpu1.clock
;
```